# Regex replace pattern, cannot locate what this does

Tags: c#, regex

Cannot figure out what this regex pattern does. Searches in google just return generic regex uses. Help please!!!

```
const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";
return Regex.Replace(inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
```

Comment: can you not use the  `string.Replace()` method..? [RegEx.Replace() Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above replaces all HTML style tags with an empty space. It matches as follows:

```
< - Match the < character literally
.*? - Match any single character that is not a line break character 
      between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed
> - Match the > character literally
```

The replacement call says: replace all matches of `HTML_TAG_PATTERN` in `inputString` with `string.Empty`.

Comment: I think you mean `.*` in the second line.

Comment: Note the `*` only matches any character because it follows a `.`

Comment: @Paul: Yep. Thanks. Corrected. Aravol: Was correcting when you commented.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it through a regex tester (any of a dozen of which canbe found via a search)

- Seeing as the angle brackets (`<` and `>`) aren't typical Regex
  syntax, those symbols get matched exactly.
- The `.` means "any character except newline"
- the `*` means "zero or more of the preceding element"
- the `?` means "zero or one of the preceding element" (**EDIT**: also "as few as possible" since it'll avoid matching this element if it can)

In all, this will match against any text in angle brackets - it's probably looking for HTML/XML tags.

Comment: A quantifier followed by `?` means as few times as possible, not zero or one.

Comment: @sln was phrasing from the documentation I use, but you would be correct